# sql tables Select from multiple tables with common Id

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I Am a ASP.NET developer & is using SQL server compact edition(.sdf) database Where I have Four Tables -

1. matrimonial(user_ID, response_ID, [other columns] )
2. responses(user_ID, response_ID, [other columns] )
3. Image(response_ID, image)
4. user (user_ID, [other columns])

the Response_ID is auto generated & user_ID is inserted
Now, a user can post a ad in matrimonial table OR in response table OR in both the problem is when user posts in both tables
Then, First I Insert data in user table then Use the Id & insert THE user_id in matrimonial Or Response table but as a user can post multiple ad 
EXAMPLE -1 ad in matrimonial with 3 images & 1 in response with 2 images

 Now as The response_ID generated in both table is 1
How can i use Joins With Image table as there are now 5 images with same response_ID how can I differentiate between 5 images that 3 are from matrimonial & 2 are from response
my query is selecting currently all 5 images
Thank You

Comment: DISTINCT will remove duplicates. To know which table you select from you need to include that information which then would counter the DISTINCT, so the question is - if multiple entries exits (matrimonial and/or response) - which distinct do you want?

Comment: Please post your current query, with current output, and expected output